# How do I approach fixing this tuple length error in read_mist_models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, astronomy

Here's the code I used:

```
import read_mist_models

filename = 'MIST_iso_61ca3125bac7d.iso.cmd'
iso = read_mist_models.ISOCMD(filename)
```

Here's the error I'm getting (added the arrows):

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-4ce42af33094> in <cell line: 4>()
2 
3 filename = 'MIST_iso_61ca3125bac7d.iso.cmd'
---> 4 iso = read_mist_models.ISOCMD(filename)

1 frames
/content/read_mist_models.py in read_isocmd_file(self)
180             for eep in range(num_eeps):
181                 isocmd_chunk = data[3+counter+eep]
---> 182            isocmd[eep]=tuple(isocmd_chunk)
183             isocmd_set.append(isocmd)
184             ages.append(isocmd[0][1])
 
ValueError: could not assign tuple of length 34 to structure with 33 fields.
```

Here's a link to the repo with the read_mist_models module:
https://github.com/jieunchoi/MIST_codes/blob/master/scripts/read_mist_models.py

I tried to read through the module and couldn't really understand what was happening. I was expecting it to just say "Reading in: MIST_iso_61ca3125bac7d.iso.cmd" (which it did) with no errors.

Comment: I would approach it by figuring out which of the 34 elements in the tuple is the one that does not match any of the 33 fields, and then omitting that element.